# Binding data after an AJAX call with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular after making a `GET` request I have to do the following to match up all the values up.

```
 promise.then(function(object){

  $scope.name = object.name
  $scope.domain = object.domain
  etc

})
```

There must be a better way to do this so I don't have to hardcode all the values i.e.

```
$scope = object
```

or maybe a loop that matches them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just assign that entire object to a `$scope` variable:

```
$scope.myObject = object;
```

Then reference in code `{{myObject.name}}` and so on.

Or, if you want to loop:

```
for (var key in object) {
    $scope[key] = object[key];
}
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without having to reference it inside another object. I would like to continue to use $scope.name, $scope.domain not $scope.myobject.name etc

Comment: can you not loop and assign the key values back somehow?

Comment: You can...Ill post an example of looping

Comment: thats the baby! thanks I could see that in my head but being new to this I was unsure. again thanks.